# How to disable auto format code in VSC only for a specific block in LUA?

Tags: visual-studio-code, lua

ive got a block of code representing a map and i dont want this block to be formatted on save.

```
game.map =  {
     
    {10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 61, 10, 13, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 13, 14, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15},
    {10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 10, 10, 10, 13, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 14, 15, 15, 129, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 68, 15, 15},
    {10, 10, 61, 10, 11, 19, 19, 19, 11, 10, 10, 13, 10, 10, 169, 10, 10, 10, 10, 13, 14, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15},
    {10, 10, 10, 11, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 11, 10, 13, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 13, 14, 15, 15, 15, 68, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15},
```

after save i've got this :

```
    {
        10,
        10,
        10,
        10,
        10,
        10,
        10,
        10,
        10,
        61,
        10,
        13,
        10,
        10,
        10,
        10,
        10,
        10,
        13,
        14,
        15,
        15,
        15,
        15,
        15,
        15,
        15,
        15,
        15,
        15,
        15,
        15
    },
    {
        10,
        10,
        10,
        10,
```

Im using : vscode-lua by trixnz in addon for formatting my lua code

Is there any comment line to add for do that in Lua ?

Comment: I am not aware of something like that. alternatively you could store the map in an extra file

Comment: Maybe not the most beautiful solution, but `loadstring[[{your map as multiline string}]]()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coercien against Coercien
As Luke in the comment mentioned the Longstring format should be untouched by VS (vscode-lua)

```
game.map = loadstring([[return({{10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 61, 10, 13, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 13, 14, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15},
{10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 10, 10, 10, 13, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 14, 15, 15, 129, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 68, 15, 15},
{10, 10, 61, 10, 11, 19, 19, 19, 11, 10, 10, 13, 10, 10, 169, 10, 10, 10, 10, 13, 14, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15},
{10, 10, 10, 11, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 11, 10, 13, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 13, 14, 15, 15, 15, 68, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15}})]])()
```

Tested in Lua 5.1 Standalone

```
> game = {}
> game.map = loadstring([[return({{10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 61, 10, 13, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 13, 14, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15},
{10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 10, 10, 10, 13, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 14, 15, 15, 129, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 68, 15, 15},
{10, 10, 61, 10, 11, 19, 19, 19, 11, 10, 10, 13, 10, 10, 169, 10, 10, 10, 10, 13, 14, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15},
{10, 10, 10, 11, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 11, 10, 13, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 13, 14, 15, 15, 15, 68, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15}})]])()
> return(#game.map)
4
> for i = 1, #game.map do print(table.concat(game.map[i], ', ')) end
10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 61, 10, 13, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 13, 14, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15
10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 10, 10, 10, 13, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 14, 15, 15, 129, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 68, 15, 15
10, 10, 61, 10, 11, 19, 19, 19, 11, 10, 10, 13, 10, 10, 169, 10, 10, 10, 10, 13, 14, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15
10, 10, 10, 11, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 11, 10, 13, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 13, 14, 15, 15, 15, 68, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15
```

PS: Did you ask trixnz about the mess?